# MaxMessageSizeExceededException

Tags: java, парсер, weblogic

Проблема в том что мой *parser* может обрабатывать сообщения размером 10000000, а на входе блобовый файл размером 10000080 превышает допустимый размер.

Сервер - *Weblogic 10*;
БД - *Oracle*

Ситуация такая: когда я принимаю данные обрабатываю и сажаю в другие таблицы, мой *parser* нормально себя ведет когда в поле типом *Blob* не большие данные, а когда большие, включается демон и дает мне `MaxMessageSizeExceededException`;

Я в настройках *Weblogic* увеличил `maxsize` сообщения, но это не особо помогло,  все равно получаю `MaxMessageSizeExceededException`.

В чем проблема?

Comment: `parser`, `message` - это какие-то штуки специально разработанные для `WebLogic`-а и как-то управляемые его параметром `maxsize`? На   какой вход подаётся блобовый? А размер его тоже измеряется в сообщениях? Или в попугаях? Ничего не понятно.

Comment: Нужно побольше деталей, что за сообщения (JMS или что там) что за БД куда пишете - в общем раскройте вопрос, иначе ничего непонятно. Штатный экстрасенс как назло в отпуске ))

Comment: В каком месте включается демон, выдающий MaxMessageSizeExceededException? а) при приёмке данных, б) при обработке, в) при посадке в другие таблицы? Приёмка откуда и чем?

Comment: Вот такой параметр не пробовали добавить при запуске клиента `-Dweblogic.MaxMessageSize=_ваш_размер_`